# Finding the value of an analytic function outside of a simple closed contour $C$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $g(z)= \int_C \dfrac{2s^2-s-2}{s-z}ds, (z \neq 3)$, with $C$ being $|z|=3$.

So to compute $g(z_0)$ with $z_0$ inside the contour, we apply Cauchy's integral formula.

What do I do if $z_0$ isn't inside the contour

Comment: Apply Cauchy's integral _theorem_.

Comment: @DanielFischer I thought Cauchy's integral formula could only be used of $z$ is in the closed contour

Comment: I wrote "integral _theorem_", not "integral formula".